# Virtual login code failing

Tags: authentication

We used the below code to virtually login the user to the Sitecore version 9.2

```
Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User virtualUser = AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("extranet\\user1", true);
virtualUser.Profile.Save();
AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(virtualUser);
```

But it's failing and throwing below error, is there any known issue/workaround for virtual login in Sitecore 9.2.

Note - Referred all the posts related to virtual login in this forum but nothing works out.

```
{
    "Message":"An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage":"UserId not found.",
    "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace":"at 
        Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.d__42.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
        at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.ClaimsIdentityFactory`2.d__0.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() 
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Identity.MembershipUserManager.d__8.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Identity.ApplicationSignInManager.d__18.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager`2.d__2.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Identity.ApplicationSignInManager.d__19.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func)  
        at Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Security.AuthenticationManager.Login(User user)   
        at VirtualAuthController.UserLogin() in C:\\Controllers\\VirtualAuthController.cs:line 50   
        at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )   
        at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.c__DisplayClass6_2.b__2(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)   
        at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__1.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__6.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.d__5.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()   
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__3.MoveNext()
        --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   
        at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()  
        at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)   
        at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"
    }
```

> Update - Issue is only in Sitecore 9.2 the same code is working in
>   Sitecore 9.1

Comment: Is it crashing on save or LoginVirtualUser?

Comment: Did you find any solution on this error? I have the exact same error on Sitecore 9.2. It is crashing on the LoginVirtualUser method

Comment: It seems like a defect.. not able to get a patch, so as an alternate moved to form authentication as a temp work-around on CDS servers.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue on Sitecore 9.1. I contacted Sitecore Support, there was a KB article which was detailing performance issues when multiple virtual users log in quickly after another.

Link to KB article: https://kb.sitecore.net/en/Articles/2020/03/11/14/01/132937.aspx

Using the .Net stopwatch, I saw login times reduced from 7-10 seconds to 100ms.

Comment: We were having this exact issue where no users were able to log in suddenly. Applied the hotfix resolved the issue for us

Answer (score 0):

I use the below code to create and login the virtual user. The code is part of a helper class and accepts username ,displayname arguments.

```
 //Create virtual User
                User virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser(userName, false);

                virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.Load();
                virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.AddedRoles.Clear();
                virtualUser.Roles.RemoveAll();

                // Optional: Add the user to an existing extranet role
                virtualUser.Roles.Add(Role.FromName("AzureAdB2C\\"));

                // set profile properties
                virtualUser.Profile.Email = userName;
                virtualUser.Profile.Name = displayName;
                virtualUser.Profile.FullName = displayName;
                virtualUser.Profile.Comment = "User Created from Some IDS";

                virtualUser.Profile.Save();
                virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.IsVirtual = true;

                virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.Save();
                user = virtualUser;
                _res = true;
                virtualUser.Profile.Reload();

                // Login the virtual user
                Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(virtualUser);
```

Comment: I guess this is similar to my code above and getting the same error.. is this working in Sitecore 9.2.? Because my code works in earlier versions till 9.1

Comment: no i worked on 9.1 with this

Comment: Reach out to support i guess

Comment: i think that might be my take away here, because it works in 9.1 but not in 9.2

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work, you can give it a try

```
var virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("sitecore\\demo@demo.com", true);
  //virtualUser.Profile.IsAdministrator = true;
  virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.IsAdministrator =true;
  Sitecore.Security.UserProfile profile = virtualUser.Profile;
  profile.IsAdministrator = true;
  profile.Save();
  Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.LoginVirtualUser(virtualUser);
```

Comment: I don't think that this line is proper   profile.IsAdministrator = true;
because my virtual users are not admin.

Comment: No but it is also comment out or you can delete it if you want but then remember to add relevant roles if you need to go into the Sitecore client

Comment: okay got.. it anyways fails in 9.2

Answer (score 0):

After setting the following settings to false the error is gone:

- `Owin.Authentication.Enabled`
- `FederatedAuthentication.Enabled`

**Caution**: on CM, this disables the default authentication which could cause problems, although you can disable on CD servers if you don't need Owin authentication.

Sitecore provides example patch files which you can enable to disable identity server:

- `App_Config\Include\Examples\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Disabler.config`
- `App_Config\Include\Examples\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.Disabler.config`